# Create jquery array object in view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

My problem is under each loop i am able to get only one last value in json.how can i create json array,i want to learn that
I am having model.

```
public class ProductModel() {
    public string productname {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string productgui {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string unit {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

Jquery Code in View

```
var productPairs;
$('#tabletest tr').each(function () {
    var productName = $(this).find(".productName").attr("id");
    var productUnit = $(this).find(".productUnit").attr("id");
    var productGuid = $(this).find(".productGuid").attr("id");
    alert(productName + "," + productUnit + "," + productGuid);
    productPairs = {
        ProductName: productName,
        NumOfProduct: productUnit,
        GuidID: productGuid,
        SelectedProductId: Guids
    };
```

Comment: You will need to provide more of your HTML/jQuery than that, at the moment it really isnt clear what is going on.

Comment: I want to create jsonarray object..but rightnow...I am getting only one value of productpairs..how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your loop iterates (or, rather, every time you execute the function in the call to `.each()`), you overwrite the previous value:

```
productPairs = {
    ProductName: productName,
    NumOfProduct: productUnit,
    GuidID: productGuid,
    SelectedProductId: Guids
};
```

If you want it to be an array of all values, first declare it as an (empty) array:

```
var productPairs = [];
```

Then in your loop (or, rather, in the call to `.each()`), `push` the value onto the array:

```
productPairs.push({
    ProductName: productName,
    NumOfProduct: productUnit,
    GuidID: productGuid,
    SelectedProductId: Guids
});
```

(Note: This has nothing to do with a view, or MVC, or any server-side technology, or AJAX, or even jQuery.  This is just a JavaScript array.)

Comment: Ok..then if i want to pass this productpair object into ajax..how can i achieve that...will this work data:Json.Stringify(productpairs)

Comment: @Rajubhai: An array can serialize into JSON just like any other JavaScript object, yes.

Comment: Ok then if I want to pass this into Controller ..like this public Actionresult test(ProductPair object)..will this object..will I get array object

Comment: @Rajubhai: Potentially, if the model binder understands the data being sent.  You can test it to find out, of course.